# How to read from JSON at specific location

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file as

```
"user1": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "creditcard-generator": "*"
}

"user2": {
"body-parser": "^1.12.2",
"creditcard-generator": "*"
}
```

I am trying to read from this file from specific location. So far I am not able to figure out how to do so. Say, I want to pick user credentials only for user2. How do i accomplish that in javascript? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: 1. It's not a JSON file. 2. Show what did you try and in what environment (node, browser, something else).

Answer (score 1):

*Complementing the answer provided by fljs.*

First thing: your json in invalid. You should put it in an array, and separate the objects using a comma.

```
  var model = {  
    "user1": {
        "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
        "creditcard-generator": "*"
           },

    "user2": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "creditcard-generator": "*"
            }
     }
```

Now you want to read that information:

```
> model["user2"]["creditcard-generator"]
< "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json file is invalide ,

```
 var text =    {

    "user1": {
        "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
        "creditcard-generator": "*"
    },

    "user2": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "creditcard-generator": "*"
    }
    }
```

you can parse like this

console.log(text.user2);

Comment: okay, so now how do I read it, say get the body-parser and creditcard-generator values for user2?

Comment: I tried var fs = require('fs');
            var content = fs.readFileSync('./actions/writeTo.json');
            var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
          
            console.log(json.user1);

It does not work. This is the error from the json file 
Failed: Unexpected token v
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token v

Comment: My json file is :

var json = {

    "user1": {
        "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
        "creditcard-generator": "*"
    },

    "user2": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "creditcard-generator": "*"
    }

}

Comment: you are wrote wrong in console. write console.log(jsonContent.user1) instead of console.log(json.user1)

Comment: JSON.parse() is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object.

Your code turns the object into a string (by calling .toString()) in order to try to parse it as JSON text.
The default .toString() returns "[object Object]", which is not valid JSON; hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward. 
Let's assume you get your file into a variable like this

```
var JSON={"user1": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "creditcard-generator": "*"
},

"user2": {
"body-parser": "^1.12.2",
"creditcard-generator": "*"
}}
```

In your Javascript, you use the dot operator, to refer to a particular element and it's children.

> Say, I want to pick user credentials only for user2.

In Javascript, you simply write `JSON.user2` and so on.
The quickest way to try this, is copy and paste the var JSON part in your console. And hit `JSON.user2`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-Object normally Looks like this (note the {} at the beginning and end):

```
var json = 
{
    "user1": {
        "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
        "creditcard-generator": "*"
    },
    "user2": {
        "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
        "creditcard-generator": "*"
    }
}
```

Now you can get the value of user2 by `json.user2`.

There are other Methods to get the data and questions to be answered: Do you have a JSON-Object or a JSON-Array? Did you already parsed it?

Look at this article: http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Greetings, Nico

Comment: got it, I am pretty new to json. can you tell me how do I access this file. So like in javascript I normally use 

var fs =  require('fs');
var file = './actions/writeTo.json';

 and then to write to it,
 jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, function(error){...}

Similary, how do I fetch the json file here?

Comment: @BishwaroopChakraborty: If you have a json-File on your Server nomally you get it with a http-Request, p.e. with JQuery: `$.get( "/Actions/writeTo.json", function( data ) { });` If you have the data you have to parse it and then you have your json/js-Object which you can access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a spesific node just access it like this:

```
 jsonObj["user2"].body-parser;
```

If you nees something more genreic you can use this function:

```
var x = data.key1.children.key4;

var path = "data";
function search(path, obj, target) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            if (obj[k] === target)
                return path + "['" + k + "']"
            else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
                var result = search(path + "['" + k + "']", obj[k], target);
                if (result)
                    return result;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
//Then for evry node that you need you can call the search() function.
var path = search(path, data, x);
console.log(path); //data['key1']['children']['key4']
```

**Note that you first have to fix your JSON to be a valid structure.**